# How to wait until file is uploaded using Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload, axios

I'm working on a Reactjs project where I can upload and download files.

But when I upload a file, the request PUT from Axios is completed before the file is fully uploaded to my database.
I use the onUploadProgress from Axios and it shows directly 100% after I click on the upload button whereas the file is not uploaded yet.

It even seems that the upload of the file on the back side is only starts once the progress bar reaches 100%.
I don't know how to correctly synchronize the progress bar with the file uploading.

**My code**

**Front**

```
  onUpload() {
    const data = new FormData();
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.selectedFile.length; i++) {
      data.append("file", this.state.selectedFile[i]);
    }
    axios
      .put("http://localhost:5000/api/files/upload", data, {
        onUploadProgress: ProgressEvent => {
          this.setState({
            loaded: Math.round(
              (ProgressEvent.loaded * 100) / ProgressEvent.total
            )
          });
        }
      })
      .then(res => {
        console.log("File(s) uploaded", res);
      });
  }
```

**Back**

```
export const uploadFile = (req, res) => {
  const myFile = (Array.isArray(req.files.file)
    ? req.files.file
    : [req.files.file]
  ).filter(e => e);
  // upload file(s) to directory
  for (let i = 0; i < myFile.length; i++) {
    myFile[i].mv("./src/uploads/" + myFile[i].name, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).send(err);
      }
    });
    // save file(s) to database
    Upload.create({
      type: myFile[i].mimetype,
      name: myFile[i].name,
      data: myFile[i].data
    });
  }
  res.send("file uploaded !");
};
```

By the way I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload for file upload

**EDIT**

```
  onUpload() {
    const data = new FormData();
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.selectedFile.length; i++) {
      data.append("file", this.state.selectedFile[i]);
    }
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/api/files/upload", data, {
        headers: {
          "Content-type": "multipart/form-data"
        },
        onUploadProgress: ProgressEvent => {
          this.setState({
            loaded: Math.round(
              (ProgressEvent.loaded * 100) / ProgressEvent.total
            )
          });
        }
      })
      .then(res => {
        console.log("File(s) uploaded", res);
      });
  }
```

Comment: Two things doesn't seem right for me, you're using the PUT method which is not appropriate because you're creating new entries in the DB (so prefer using POST), and you're not passing the content-type header `multipart/form-data` (the second one is the most important) Try using this content-type header

Comment: There is no way to communicate from server to front end about the progress, unless you want to make a server call in every milisecond about the progress. I would suggest you to make progress bar to 95% in onUploadprogress event and complete the remaining when promise complete in .then event.

Comment: @MehdiBenmoha for some tests I created the upload button, usually this code is called by my submit button and the multipart/form-data is inside the form.
I changed my code as you can see in my edit but nothing has changed.

Comment: @SachinVishwakarma how can I do that ?

Comment: added answer as a reply to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
onUpload() {
const data = new FormData();
for (var i = 0; i < this.state.selectedFile.length; i++) {
  data.append("file", this.state.selectedFile[i]);
}
axios
  .post("http://localhost:5000/api/files/upload", data, {
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "multipart/form-data"
    },
    onUploadProgress: ProgressEvent => {
      this.setState({
        loaded: 95
      });
    }
  })
  .then(res => {
   this.setState({
        loaded: 100
      });
    console.log("File(s) uploaded", res);
  });
```

}

Comment: I tried your solution but my progress goes direct to 100%. I think my post request is send and then my file starts to be uploaded

Comment: yes exactly that is happening... you need to fool the frontend or assume that it is gonna finish in 2-3 second as an average time and show the progress accordingly

Answer (score -1):

You are setting state as soon as you're hitting the API, the reason you're getting 100% as soon as the API hits. I would suggest you to pass `"status = success"` or `"status = 201"` from server side So that you can wait for a response in client side. i.e :-

```
onUpload() {
    const data = new FormData();
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.selectedFile.length; i++) {
      data.append("file", this.state.selectedFile[i]);
    }
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/api/files/upload", data, {
        headers: {
          "Content-type": "multipart/form-data"
        }
      })
      .then(res => {
        if(res.status === 'success') {
              onUploadProgress: ProgressEvent => {
               this.setState({
                 loaded: Math.round(
                (ProgressEvent.loaded * 100) / ProgressEvent.total
              )
           });
         }
        }
        console.log("File(s) uploaded", res);
      });
  }
```

Comment: There is an issue with the syntax or something like this : `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression` on the line `onUploadProgress: ProgressEvent =>`

Comment: If you remove 'onUploadProgress: ProgressEvent => {}' keeping the setState then your code will get compiled but I am not sure if it works for you. For better clarification, can you update the code on codesandbox?

Comment: I'm trying but I have to change the code to fit with codesandbox. I can give you a github repository if you want.